# Set which rows to delete on mysql after applying combined unique index w/ignore

Tags: mysql, indexing

Supose I have a table with several columns.
I know how to find duplicates, and then to keep just one record with this expression, adding a combinated index...

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE part3 ADD UNIQUE INDEX (gtu, region, trait, pop, author, risk)
```

...but I would like to be able to control which will be the deleted row; not just the one with the "*first row of rows with duplicates on a unique key*", as stated here in the [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html). 
I mean, i exactly want to specify that the non-deleted row must be the one with the minor value in column field called *zvalue*.

Any suggestion?? Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Delete first? Then alter table?

Comment: hummm... Im quite a newbie to mysql; so how could i compare the duplicates pairwise in order to DELETE the one with the lowest zvalue for each pair? Dont know if it is possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to delete what you don't need, try to think of it as a problem whereby you want to pick the ones you want and ignore the rest; like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `other_table` LIKE `part3`;
INSERT INTO `other_table`
SELECT `part3`.*
FROM (SELECT gtu, region, trait, pop, author, risk, MAX(zvalue) AS max_zval
    FROM `part3`
    GROUP BY gtu, region, trait, pop, author, risk
) `tmp`
INNER JOIN `part3` USING (gtu, region, trait, pop, author, risk)
WHERE `part3`.zvalue = `tmp`.max_zval;
```

That should create a table `other_table` that satisfies the unique constraint in your data; only the rows with the highest `zvalue` are kept, the others removed (skipped).

Comment: Hey @Jack, thank u!!!
I looked at your command and understood it now, and i guess it surely work... but when i run it, mysql returns me a sintaxis error which i can't identify... would you give me a hand?? ;)