# mysql if there is a duplicate retrieve the most recent date of it

Tags: php, mysql, database

My previous post was confusing.

This is how my table data loks:

```
   id | firstname | lastname | email             |  modified_date         | preference_1 |pref.. 
   1  | steven    | smith    | steven@gmail.com     2013-06-10 04:01:25   | Player       | dot
   2  | Bill      | Johnson  | bill@gmail.com    |  2014-06-10 04:01:25   | code         | pow
   3  | steven    | smith    | steven@gmail.com  |  2014-10-10 12:01:25   | pol          | pl
```

I have 3 columns preference_1, preference_2 and preference_3
The reason why I do a subselect is concat them into one column.

The query below works fine, however, it returns duplicate email addresses. 
If there is a duplicate it should return the latest modified_date

so it should return row number 2 and 3. It should not return row number 1 since the email address is the same as row number 3  but with an older modified date

```
  SELECT
    users.firstname,
    users.lastname,
    users.email,
    users.pref
   FROM (
    SELECT
        users.firstname,
        users.lastname,
        users.email,
        users.status,
        users.active,
        CONCAT(
            users.preference_1, ',',
            users.preference_2, ',', 
            users.preference_3
        ) AS pref
    FROM users
) AS users

  WHERE  users.status = 1
  AND users.active = 1
  GROUP BY users.id
  LIMIT 10000
```

Comment: Take a look to this question. Its a similar problem I had, but instead of keeping the most recent date, keeping the smaller number for in a field for duplicated rows.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756203/set-which-rows-to-delete-on-mysql-after-applying-combined-unique-index-w-ignore
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a sub query to get the max modified date grouped by email address, and join that against users.

Something like this.

```
SELECT
        users.firstname,
        users.lastname,
        users.email,
        users.status,
        users.active,
        CONCAT(
            users.preference_1, ',',
            users.preference_2, ',', 
            users.preference_3
        ) AS pref
FROM users
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT email, MAX(modified_date) AS modified_date
    FROM users
    WHERE status = 1
    AND active = 1
    GROUP BY email
) sub0
ON users.email = sub0.email
AND users.modified_date = sub0.modified_date
WHERE  users.status = 1
AND users.active = 1
```